# Code Analysis rule CA1062 behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, fxcop

I have following extension method for strings:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string target)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(target);
}
```

... and in the code I use it as follows:

```
public static string DoSomethingOnString(this string target)
{
    if (target.IsNullOrEmpty())
        return target;

    target = target.Trim();  //This line causes CA1062 violation

    return target;
}
```

Now, if I run code analysis on this, I get a violation of rule [CA1062](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CA1062%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETPortable,Version=v4.0%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true).
But if I change the code to:

```
public static string DoSomethingOnString(this string target)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(target))  //CHANGED LINE
        return target;

    target = target.Trim();  //This line DOES NOT cause CA1062 violation anymore

    return target;
}
```

... then it is fine.

Why it thinks that I'm not checking for null condition in the first example? Does it check only for string.IsNullOrEmpty or string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace? Is there a way to make CA recognize my extension method, or I'll need to suppress this rule?

**UPDATE:**
If you have the same issue you can vote on feedback item I submitted on MS Connect:
[Code Analysis rule CA1062 raises false alarm](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780543/code-analysis-rule-ca1062-raises-false-alarm)

Comment: *Where* is the violation? In the extension method? In the call *to* the extension method? Or after it? Whenever you mention an error/warning in a question, *please* show where it occurs.

Comment: Look at the IL code, the code analysis does not operate on the code you see in your IDE, so maybe this will help.

Comment: You could use the `ValidatedNotNullAttribute` to let FxCop know. More here: http://esmithy.net/2011/03/15/suppressing-ca1062/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why it thinks that I'm not checking for null condition in the first example?

Quite simply, FxCop doesn't understand that if your `IsNullOrEmpty` extension method does the same thing as `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. It doesn't realize that if `target` is null, `IsNullOrEmpty` will return `true` and your method will exit. Basically I suspect it has in-built knowledge of `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/contracts) is more likely to have success here, as I believe FxCop only performs a relatively shallow check on what your code does, compared with the deep reasoning of Code Contracts. You could decorate your `IsNullOrEmpty` method with [`ValidatedNotNullAttribute`](http://esmithy.net/2011/03/15/suppressing-ca1062/) to inform FxCop what's going on.

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty([ValidatedNotNullAttribute] this string target)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(target);
}
//The naming is important to inform FxCop
sealed class ValidatedNotNullAttribute : Attribute { }
```

This is just an example of where code analysis can sometimes be a little too eager to criticize. It's something I've seen with pretty much every code analysis tool I've used. Your choices are usually along the lines of:

- Change your code to work around the code analysis tool, even if it was fine before
- Suppress the rules at specific sites, after manually checking each of them
- Suppress whole rules if they frequently give false positives
- Abandon the code analysis tool entirely

You should also log a bug or feature request, of course...

Comment: I updated code samples with comment on the line causing the violation.

Comment: @Anil: Right - that's just a matter of FxCop not "understanding" what your method will do.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I submitted a feedback item with sample project on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780543/code-analysis-rule-ca1062-raises-false-alarm#details)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like they finally got around to fixing this in the roslyn analyzers.

Bug report here:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/2369